# C++/CLI Lambda Selector for LINQ Static Methods

Tags: c++, linq, visual-studio-2012, lambda, c++-cli

I have this in C++/CLI (Visual Studio 2012)

```
Enumerable::Max((IEnumerable<IFoo^>^) Foos, [](IFoo^ f){return f->Id;});
```

But it results in this error:

> No instance of overloaded function "System::Linq::Enumerable::Max"
>   matches argument list

Its driving me batty because there is nothing wrong with the lambda. Do I need to cast it to a Func somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++/CLI compiler doesn't support C++11 lambda expressions, they are not convertible to a delegate object.  Although .NET had a big head-start, support for managed lambdas was never added and surely never will.

You'll need a delegate object with a helper function that returns IFoo->id, could look like this:

```
int returnId(IFoo^ obj) { return obj->Id;  }
...
    int max = Enumerable::Max((IEnumerable<IFoo^>^) Foos, 
                              gcnew Func<IFoo^, int>(returnId));
```

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, lambdas in Visual C++ are still native-only.  You definitely should say what compiler version you're using.

Have you tried

```
Func<IFoo^, IdType>^ conversion = [](IFoo^ f){return f->Id;};
Enumerable::Max((IEnumerable<IFoo^>^) Foos, conversion);
```

That will separate delegate creation from overload resolution... I'm quite certain the error has nothing to do with the LINQ method.

Comment: Unfortunately I get a "No Suitable Conversion exists" if I try that top line to set `conversion`. and I'm using Visual Studio 2012 U3